# Are there regional constraints with the SIMCom modules? (Eg. SIM7605CE/SIM7600CE)

Tags: arduino, gsm, at-commands, sim, simcom

I recently received a SIMCom Module (Model no. SIM7605CE), shown below.
[image]
The item can be  ([purchased online as well](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000933839184.html)). The device, much like the ones used with Arduinos (like the SIM800L), is supposed to respond to AT commands. However, it does not recognize the SIM card that I use (here in Malaysia). I wanted to know if anyone else had a similar experience. And is it possible that this particular model does not operate in South Asia? The AT responses are given below.

```
ATI
Manufacturer: SIMCOM INCORPORATED
Model: SIMCOM_SIM7605CE-CNSE
Revision: SIM7605M11_A_V3.0
IMEI: 869404040055042
+GCAP: +CGSM

OK

AT+CSQ
+CSQ: 99,99

OK

AT+CCID
+CCID: 89601618113007656907

OK

AT+CREG?
+CREG: 0,0

OK

AT+COPS?
+COPS: 0

OK

AT+CBC
+CBC: 3.730V

OK
```

Comment: I am also using SIM7600, but I am confused. I always thing that no matter where you test it, the AT protocol always works. It is only when you try high level things, such as GPS, or SMS, then you find things not working.

Answer (score 1):

In 2018 Network Operators changed some specifications in SIM cards protocol.

Happened that some SIM cards quit to work.

To fix the problem you might have to update the firmware if your module.

---

I and my team had to update the firmware of 5000 Gemalto BGS2 modules back in 2018.

For the sake of knowledge: each update lasts 20 minutes.

Comment: Thing is, I downloaded the latest firmware and started on this device literally a couple of days before I put this post up. So I don't think it's a firmware issue, right?

Comment: You should change SIM or contact SIMCOM support.

Comment: Tried two different SIM cards, and sent an email to SIMCOM, no reply from them either...will look for alternative solutions.

Comment: Ok, consider Gemalto, Quectel, Sierra Wireless.